# Convert single strings into an single array group

Tags: php, mysql

I need to convert a multiple single values into an array, basically I managed to get names from the source as a string, but it's as the following:

All single strings:

```
DBG --> [string] date
DBG --> [string] conversion_time
DBG --> [string] conversion_ref
DBG --> [string] cookie_id
DBG --> [string] customer_id
DBG --> [string] browser
DBG --> [string] operating_system
DBG --> [string] site_search_string
DBG --> [string] page_url
DBG --> [string] store_viewed
DBG --> [string] store_search_string
DBG --> [string] product_id
DBG --> [string] category_id
DBG --> [string] basket_product_ids
```

I would like to convert it into an array so I can merge with another set of data to generate a file. The key of the array would be exactly the same as the value, so I'm looking to get it like this:

```
DBG --> [array] Array
(
    [date] => date
    [conversion_time] => conversion_time
    [conversion_ref] => conversion_ref
    [cookie_id] => cookie_id
    [customer_id] => customer_id
    [browser] => browser
    [operating_system] => operating_system
    [site_search_string] => site_search_string
    [page_url] => page_url
    [store_viewed] => store_viewed
    [store_search_string] => store_search_string
    [product_id] => product_id
    [category_id] => category_id
    [basket_product_ids] => basket_product_ids
)
```

How would I do that in PHP? I have been trying to convert string to array and repeat the value but it returns also as single ones: `$array = array($names => $names);`

```
DBG --> [array] Array
(
    [date] => date
)

DBG --> [array] Array
(
    [conversion_time] => conversion_time
)

DBG --> [array] Array
(
    [conversion_ref] => conversion_ref
)
```

What do I need to do to get everything aligned?

I'm a bit of a newbie with coding.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare a variable with a string in a pair of chain bracket and you have yourself an associative array. e.g. `$array["name1"]="value1";` add more values... `$array["name2"]="value2";`

**Therefore use this to set values individually:**

```
$DBG["date_key"] = "date_value";
$DBG["conversion_time_key"] = "conversion_time_value";
$DBG["conversion_ref_key"] = "conversion_ref_value";
$DBG["cookie_id_key"] = "cookie_id_value";
$DBG["customer_id_key"] = "customer_id_value";
$DBG["browser_key"] = "browser_value";
$DBG["operating_system_key"] = "operating_system_value";
$DBG["site_search_string_key"] = "site_search_string_value";
$DBG["page_url_key"] = "page_url_value";
$DBG["store_viewed_key"] = "store_viewed_value";
$DBG["store_search_string_key"] = "store_search_string_value";
$DBG["product_id_key"] = "product_id_value";
$DBG["category_id_key"] = "category_id_value";
$DBG["basket_product_ids_key"] = "basket_product_ids_value";
```

**Or use the following if you need to set all values at once:**

```
$DBG=array(
    ["date_key"] => "date_value",
    ["conversion_time_key"] => "conversion_time_value",
    ["conversion_ref_key"] => "conversion_ref_value",
    ["cookie_id_key"] => "cookie_id_value",
    ["customer_id_key"] => "customer_id_value",
    ["browser_key"] => "browser_value",
    ["operating_system_key"] => "operating_system_value",
    ["site_search_string_key"] => "site_search_string_value",
    ["page_url_key"] => "page_url_value",
    ["store_viewed_key"] => "store_viewed_value",
    ["store_search_string_key"] => "store_search_string_value",
    ["product_id_key"] => "product_id_value",
    ["category_id_key"] => "category_id_value",
    ["basket_product_ids_key"] => "basket_product_ids_value"
);
```

**Notice the use of `=>` instead of `=` and `,` instead of `;`**

Answer (score 0):

You can define both the key and the value of an element in an array using the string value of a variable, like so:

```
$array = [];
$string1 = 'date';
$string2 = 'time';

$array[$string1] = $string1;
$array[$string2] = $string2;

var_dump($array);
```